Does "melee" really imply confusion?
I was speaking to people in the pub and unexpectedly taught them a new word - "melee". I tried explaining it in terms of close combat but then defaulted to pulling up the dictionary definition

a situation that is confused and not under control, esp. a fight
involving a number of people: A melee erupted in the stands near the
end of the game.

There are multiple other definitions but the defining characteristic is confusion. This is totally at odds with my own understanding; sure there can be confusion involved, but I've never known it to be the overriding principle.
In role-playing games, you can select a "melee" class, which is usually confined to hand-to-hand combat. Am I to assume that my character is permanently confused? I also hear the word used regularly in historical documentaries that I listen to about battles - are they really saying that the situation was confused, rather than just referring to a general battle, and I've missed that nuance?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Different dictionaries may offer different 'dictionary definitions'. But when there is a common thread that is at odds with personal perceptions, one needs to consider it more probable that one needs to adjust one's view.

@EdwinAshworth — Same goes for the definition of confused.

melee (also mêlée) (n.)

A confused fight, skirmish, or scuffle.
The New Oxford American Dictionary [print]

melee or mêlée (n.)

A noisy, confused fight or hand-to-hand struggle among a number of
people
Webster's New World Dictionary  [print]


A noisy riotous fight or brawl.
Collins English Dictionary [print]

melee (n.)

a confused struggle
M-W


A melee is a noisy confusing fight between the people in a crowd.
Collins


a large noisy uncontrolled crowd, in which people are moving in
different directions and sometimes fighting with each other
Cambridge


A confused struggle or fight at close quarters. See Synonyms at brawl.
ahd

If I came across a fight or battle described as a melee, I'd expect  some (if not total) confusion. Even the OED definition quoted in another answer has "confused struggle".

Well it's certainly fun when this answer is in direct contradiction to the one I accepted :P

Let's see what Tinfoil Hat has to say.

@DjinTonic, much depends on what one takes to be the role of the semicolon in the definition quoted by Tinfoil Hat. But even if one takes the position that the word could be used in the absence of confusion, the definitions quoted here establish that the association of melee with confusion is strong enough that it would be unwise and potentially misleading to so use it. (The materials referred to in the last paragraph of the question may be an exception, in so far as their use of the term is based on the sense that the OED definition specifically designates as historical.)

@jsw29 I think there is also a very strong connotation that a melee is confused--so much so that a reader would be perplexed to come across an example of a melee described as "well-organized" or  one that "went off like clockwork." We should also take into account what the OP means by "imply." I take it as the "default" meaning and agree with your "unwise."

In normal use these days a melee is disorganised. A battle fought at close quarters is likely to appear disorganised to an observer. Of course it is good if you can cause your opponents to become disorganised, especially if your friends are not.

melee meaning close-combat fight (without confusion) is a term of art in video games, as well as having a usage in military history. Outside these fields, it means a confused thing. Within specific fields, it has a specialised meaning different to its everyday meaning, just as many other terms do. And many general-purpose dictionaries will not define terms from video gaming, tabletop RPGs, or other fields, if they're judged to be restricted to a narrow domain.

@StuartF  'H.G. Wells' 1913 Little Wars was the first to specifically outline a "melee" rule in his eponymous war game. Many later wargames (and video games) can trace their origins to the rulesets first laid out in Little Wars.' Wikipedia

@StuartF — There it is right in the M-W definition: “especially : a hand-to-hand fight among several people.” You can also find the relevant meaning of confused in all of the sources above: lacking clear distinction of elements; jumbled (New Oxford American) / being disordered or mixed up (M-W) / Chaotic; jumbled (American Heritage) / Confusion is a situation in which everything is in disorder, especially because there are lots of things happening at the same time (Collins)...

Here’s the first definition of mêlée from the OED:

mêlée noun
1.a. A battle or engagement at close quarters, a hand-to-hand fight; a skirmish; a confused struggle or scuffle, esp. one
involving many people. Also historical: a tournament involving two
groups of combatants. a1648– Etymology:  < French mêlée, †meslee a quarrel, a mixture (see medley n.). Compare earlier medley n. and mellay n.

Here are the senses of confusion that pertain to melees (not to be confused, so to speak, with those of mental perturbation):

confused adjective
II.3.a. Characterized by disorderly combination or intermixture; disordered, disorderly. 1576–
confusion noun
6.a. (a) Tumult, excited and disorderly commotion. (b) Civil commotion or disorder. 1555–

tl;dr: Your hand-to-hand combatant is not confused.
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)

+1 for correct spelling of mêlée

@MichaelHarvey  Other reputable British and American dictionaries have the headword as melee with mêlée as an alternative. Melee is certainly a correct English spelling, as the Ngram attests.

@DjinTonic Those diacritics on mêlée guide a French speaker in how to pronounce the word correctly. Once respelled without them, the letters used no longer align with the pronunciation, so nobody will know whether to say it like mealy or like mellay. Modern English has a dirty, nasty habit of doing this crazy thing, which causes needless confusion. Imagine if when we imported Spanish cañón, we had just left it as an undiacriticked canon instead of sensibly respelling it as canyon!

... Modern English has a dirty, nasty, but accepted habit of doing this thing.  // I was once corrected for pronouncing 'Mallet' /ˈmæleɪ/ (which is correct for the inventor of the particular articulated design that takes his name; Big Boy is an example of the type). It's largely been Anglicised now (though not totally; your pronunciation identifies your nerd-type).
